# How to enable slow query log on Google cloud postgres

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

The [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/diagnose-issues) says how to enable slow query log for MySQL but there is nothing for Postgres.

How can I enable the Postgres slow query log to debug slow queries? If there is no explicit option, how can I modify the postgres config file to add this myself?

Answer (score 2):

It's not currently possible to enable the log_min_duration_statement flag for Postgres on Cloud SQL.

This feature is being worked on and you can [follow its progress here](https://issuetracker.google.com/74578509). You can click on the star icon on the top left corner to get email notifications when some news about this feature becomes available.

Comment: I don't think it is or ever has been worked on, since the issue is now more than a year old, still has as a status of `new` and no assignee.